# Canonicalization (c14n) of XML code using PHP class method

Tags: php, xml

I found in PHP documentation a method from the DOMNode class, defined as DOMNode::C14N (https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php). Sadly i've had a hard time finding complete examples about its usage, and I have tryed some code with no success... probably due to my null experience using the PHP native classes.

```
<?php
$Document = '<Document>... (more XML code to canonicalize)</Document>';

$xml = new C14N();
$xml = $Document->C14N();
```

When executing i get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'C14N' not found in C:\wamp\www\...
```

I have researched and the class DOMNode is included in the DOM extension which is suposed to come installed and enabled by default, plus c14n is not a class but a method.

I have PHP 5.3.13.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help you reading the PHP Manual here:

```
DOMNode::C14N
```

This means for the class `DOMNode` there is a method named `C14N`.

So where to find such a **DOMNode**, so you can call that method on?

Well, **DOMDocument** for example is a **DOMNode**, see the following manual page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php it write that

```
DOMDocument extends DOMNode {
```

An extends stands for *is a*, so **DOMDocument** is a **DOMNode**. Scrolling down on that page will already give you some general example code on how to create such an object, you then only need to call the method:

```
// "Create" the document.
$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );
$xml->loadXML('<Document>... (more XML code to canonicalize)</Document>');
echo $xml->C14N();
```

Hope this helps you with your orientation.

**Example** ([Online-demo](https://eval.in/171250)):

```
<?php
// "Create" the document.
$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );
$xml->loadXML('<Document b="c"    

f="e"  a="j">...

<!-- stupid whitespace example -->

   mother told me to        go shopping
   
</Document>');

echo $xml->C14N();
```

**Program Output**

```
<Document a="j" b="c" f="e">...



   mother told me to        go shopping
   
</Document>
```

As this example shows, the attributes are sorted and the comment has been removed.